# a4j:commandLink not calling action but invoking PhaseListener

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.2, ajax4jsf

I have `a4j:commandLink` inside Jquery Dialog box.

```
 $h(document).ready(function() {
            $h("#myForm").attr("style", "display:block");
            $h("#myForm").dialog({
                duration: 800,
                height: 100,
                minWidth: 250,
                width: 250,
                position: [490, 160],
                zIndex: 99999999,
                modal: true,
                show: {
                    effect: 'puff',
                    duration: 400
                },
                hide: {
                    effect: 'puff',
                    duration: 400
                }

            });
        });


<div id="myForm" style="visibility:hidden">
<a4j:region id="hdRegion" renderRegionOnly="true">
    <a4j:commandLink immediate="true" value="Connect me &#187;" styleClass="connectMe" action="#{myBean.myMethod}" ></a4j:commandLink>
    </a4j:region>
 </div>

publid String myMethod()
{
  log.debug("Entered into myMethod");
  return null;
}
```

`myBean` is in `request` scope.

When I click on `a4j:commandLInk`, `myMethod` is not getting called. Instead my PhaseListener is getting invoked.

How can I make sure that commandLink invokes only `myMethod`?

Comment: Where is the `<h:form/>` enclosing that command link?

Comment: Am getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'action' of null" if I enclose `<h:form>`

Comment: Well that's the problem 1) The commandLink will **not** call the action method if it's not enclosed in the `<h:form/>` 2) The error you're experiencing indicates that the `<h:form/>` is also enclosing some other offending component(s). That or you're misusing the form

Comment: How can I trouble shoot in finding the offending components?